# (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager))

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-manifest

I'm working on my mobile application project, currently having problem to implement workmanager into my flutter project. When I launched the app, this exception error occur

Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method initialize on channel be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager))

already added necessary components in AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <meta-data
        android:name="flutterWorkManagerInitializationChannel"
        android:value="be.tramckrijte.workmanager/foreground_channel_work_manager" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterWorkManagerCallbackDispatcher"
        android:value="be.tramckrijte.workmanager/WorkmanagerDispatcher" />
```

but still the issue persist.

I'm fairly new to mobile application development. Hoping any devs can help me with this problem, its for my final year project

Answer (score 1):

If you are utilizing hot restart or hot reload in Flutter, it will not be sufficient for the desired outcome. This is because Flutter needs to incorporate plugin dependencies into the platform-specific sections of your application, which cannot be achieved solely through hot restart or hot reload.

You can resolve it by performing `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: Thank you for responding Mr Meet. Unfortunately, I already did use ***flutter clean*** and ***flutter pub get*** before asking on StackOverflow, it does not fix the issue. If you want further context, feel free to ask, because I'm still looking for solution